# operations on logging and nologging tables

Tags: oracle10g

I have two tables: A is logging, B is nologging. I'm executing on working production environment script like this:

```
begin
insert /*+ APPEND*/ into B select * from A; --some kind of direct load insert
update A set r=1;
end;
```

During execution of above statement there can be transactions which inserts values into A and B tables (normal, conventional inserts). I want to make sure:
- if the media failure occurs all changes can recovered (updates on B, changes made by transactions) except direct load inserts?
- if execution of the script fails, nothing will be changed by it?

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

On the other side, during `insert /*+ APPEND*/ into B select * from A;` other transactions could insert something into B or they will be waiting for resource?